# Default Cipher Suites for Istio Ingress-Gateway for Min TLS1.2

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks, envoyproxy, servicemesh

Is there a way to check the default cipher suites being used by the Ingress gateway?
My gateway has MTLS enabled with minimum TLS version as 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find it out by going through the [Mutual TLS authentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) docs:

> Istio configures `TLSv1_2` as the minimum TLS version for both client
> and server with the following cipher suites:
>
> - CDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> - AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - AES128-GCM-SHA256

Comment: I have a scenario to update the cipher suites to a different set and I am wondering how to validate the updated set?

Comment: That would be a different story. Please ask a separate question where you can describe that scenario in more detail. That would be more clear for the rest of the community (no multiple topics in one stack question).

Comment: Yes I realized later and asked a separate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337486/adding-custom-cipher-suite-to-istio-gateway