# Adding custom cipher suite to Istio Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

I have added few custom cipher suites at the gateway like this :

```
tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      credentialName: sds
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
      cipherSuites: [ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256|ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256|ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384|ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CBC-SHA256|ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA256]
```

Is there a way to validate if these cipher suites have actually been added? Does it order in the same way as we have specified?

Comment: Have you tried to test protocols via sockets - https://testssl.sh/, output should be like https://gist.github.com/pbohman/bb90150a6e62456b07f715e43ec6ee54 ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are still wondering the correct format is:

```
tls:
  mode: MUTUAL
  credentialName: sds
  minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
  maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
  cipherSuites:
  - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384
  - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CBC-SHA256
  - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384
  - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA256
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Better to add relevant description with your answer that could be helpful for readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer